# Reading binary file without knowing file format

Tags: java, file

I'm working on a java project and i have to read some files like these: 
- EntryID.data
- EntryID.index
- KeyText.data
- KeyText.index
...

I think these files are used in a dictionary project but i can't find a any document about this. How can i read them or know the format of them ? Sorry for my english =.=

Thanks alot!

Comment: Umm ... if you don't know where the files come from and you don't what they contain, why do you need to read them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *looks* like files from a database management system. One file to store the data, another one to store at least one index to speed up queries.

I'd start with a hex editor and look at the file. Sometimes, the content binaries gives a hint.

Another idea: look at the classpath and inspect property and resource files. Maybe you'll find a database driver or some config files with jdbc connect strings.

---

Google told me, **that all four files are used** by Apple's *Dictionary.app*. [Have a look at this blog](http://rixstep.com/2/20100526,00.shtml), this can point you in the correct direction.

---

Last note - reading undocumented binaries is a challenge. I usually start with [010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) to analyse the datastructure and develop a java based test tool to read the data. It's some sort of <strike>try and error</strike> evolutionary process.

Comment: Thank you guys, i'have used Hex Editor to open it, i can read some meaningful string but i still cant get the file format. The keytext.data file contains definitions of English words in vietnamese, i cant understand the content of keytext.index file. I also read a lot topic about apple dic app but i cant find anything, i will try again. Thanks in advance !

Comment: It *is* a dictionary and you can expect some sort of key/value pairs: an english word and an translation in a different language. I doubt that you can find some sort of java lib that allows using the dictionary files - concentrate on parsing the required information from the file, maybe into a new datastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is kinda difficult. *data* could mean anything.

You could try the UNIX utility [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) or open the file with a hex editor and look for interesting strings (the utility [strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_%28Unix%29) is helpful for that too).

Answer (score 0):

Some information is in info.plist.
KeyText.data is sometimes compressed using zlib. 78 9C is well-known zlib-header so you can decompress when you find it. Size of decompressed entry comes before compressed entry.
Size of entry comes before entry of array.

C# library is in https://github.com/kurema/MacDictionaryGeneral. But *.index is too difficult to understand and implement. info.plist says *.index is trie index which is not enough information to understand fully.